# why does $('<div/>').text(value).text(); not escape the HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, encoding, escaping

I'm trying to understand how html encoding and decoding works in the browser and with jQuery. I understand that the `$('<div/>').text(myString)` function will encode any < and > and a few other characters to their appropriate html entities. Thus

```
"<a>" =>"&le,a&gt;"
```

But what if I apply another call to text(), like this:

```
$('<div/>').text(myString).text()
```

This seems to decode the string once more, as opposed to this:

```
$('<div/>').text(myString).html()
```

why is that? why does the second call to text() destroy the html encoding? Perhaps my mental model of how which context is being escaped is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy the html encoding?"  Can you give us an input of `myString`, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: "why does the second call to text() destroy the html encoding?" - because by calling `.text()` you're explicitly asking it to read back the decoded text.

Comment: Explosion Pills, if myString == <a>, then $('<div/>').text(myString).text() will return "<a>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving the text of an element or node with jQuery's `.text()` uses the DOM property `.textContent` or `.innerText` (depending upon browser/version) internally inside of jQuery and returns whatever the browser returns for that.

`.text()` is, by definition NOT supposed to return HTML.  It's supposed to return just the textual content of the element or node.  If there are child nodes (e.g. HTML), then `.text()` returns a concatenation of the text nodes and leaves out the HTML nodes.

If you call `.text(someText)` and pass it some text, then jQuery does this:

```
return this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) );
```

Here, you can see that it takes the text and passes it as an argument to createTextNode so the text is passed directly to the browser to go in a single text node and NOT be interpreted as HTML.

Comment: ok, but does it not seem counterintuitive that $('<p>&lt;a&gt;</p>').html() will return "&lt;a&gt;", but $('<p>&lt;a&gt;</p>').text() will return "<a>" ?

Comment: @worker1138 - that makes perfect sense to me.  Your first example creates a "<p>" tag with `&lt;a&gt;` as the HTML which is what `.html()` returns and the text version of that HTML is `<a>` which is what `.text()` returns.